# fosuser bundle - changing password pattern

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to change the password pattern of FosUser Bundle.. (lets say, i will require the password to be minumum of 6 characters which also require 1 letter and 1 number. Where do i set this?

Answer (score 2):

Yuo can do this in FosUserBundle validator.

Take a look at this file:

```
/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml
```

Particularly:

```
<property name="plainPassword">
  <constraint name="NotBlank">
    <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
    <option name="groups">Registration</option>
  </constraint>
  <constraint name="MinLength">
    <option name="limit">2</option>
    <option name="message">fos_user.password.short</option>
    <option name="groups">
      <value>Registration</value>
      <value>Profile</value>
    </option>
  </constraint>
</property>
```

I don't know (but I suppose that I'm right) if exists a constraint of type "1 letter and 1 number".
In that case, you have to "build" it yourself and use in the same way you use the `NotBlank` and `MinLenght` constraint of this example

Answer (score 1):

I've add into User entity

```
    // src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Entity/User.php

    ....
    class User extends BaseUser{
        ....
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="fos_user.username.blank", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
         * @Assert\Length(min=5, max="255",
         *     minMessage="fos_user.username.short", maxMessage="fos_user.username.long",
         *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
         */
        protected $username;  

        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="fos_user.password.blank", groups={"Registration", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword"})
         * @Assert\Length(min=6,
         *     minMessage="fos_user.password.short",
         *     groups={"Registration", "Profile", "ResetPassword", "ChangePassword"})
         */
        protected $plainPassword;
```